# QUERY function not properly counting matching values with OR criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**[Goal]**
I'm trying to count the number of tickets per employee that has a status with either "Finished," "Finished (Scope)," or "Routed (Sales)." The data that I'm pulling from to count the tickets has the following column names.

Column A: Ticket ID,
Column B: Status,
Column C: Employee,
Column D: Date

In the formula, you'll notice that it's referring to cell H1, which the cell contains the current week with this formula: TODAY()-MOD(TODAY()-2,7)-1

**[Current Formula]**

```html
=QUERY('Data'!$A$3:$F,"Select C, COUNT(A)
      where B matches 'Finished|Finished (Scope)|Routed (Sales)'
      AND D >= "&H1&" GROUP BY C
      LABEL COUNT(A) 'Total Tickets'",0)
```

**[Issue]**
I was able to create a formula that counts the number of tickets per employee with the status called "Finished," however for some reason, it's not counting tickets that has the status name "Finished (Scope)" or "Routed (Sales)." Can someone please help?

Comment: Why not just use `IN()`? `WHERE B IN ('Finished', 'Finished (Scope)', 'Routed (Sales)')`. Then there's no problem with forgetting to escape the brackets in the regular expression.

Comment: @MatBailie `IN()` is not supported in google sheets query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a regex so you may need to escape brackets. try:

```
=QUERY('Data'!$A$3:$F,
 "select C,count(A)
  where lower(B) matches 'finished \(scope\)|routed \(sales\)|finished'
    and D >= "&H1&" 
  group by C
  label count(A) 'Total Tickets'", 0)
```

Comment: As the op may be unaware: regex are Regular Expressions, a whole language of string processing. In RegEx, brackets have specific purposes, and so to treat them as just any other character in a string, you need to 'escape' them with a `\\`